# string.replace not working in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, regex, oracle-apex

I have a number of Dynamic Actions in my Oracle Apex 4.2 page with action "Execute Javascript Code" on a phone number entry field:

```
$s("P40_MOBILE_PHONE", $v("P40_MOBILE_PHONE").replace(/[()-\s]+/g, ''));
```

This works in IE and Chrome. In Firefox, however, it not only doesn't work, but it causes all other dynamic actions on the page to stop working entirely.

The only difference between this and the other dynamic actions seems to be the use of `string.replace(/[()-\s]+/g, '')`. This is supposed to strip any spaces, `(`, `)` and `-` characters from the phone number.

Comment: try \\(\\) and \- instead of just () and  -

Comment: @dandavis, thanks, that fixed it. If you put that as an answer I'll mark it correct.

Comment: i don't think correcting a typo will be of much benefit to others; no point in a full answer to pollute searches...

Comment: If you say so. From my perspective, it wasn't a typo, I genuinely didn't know that you couldn't refer to individual characters like that in a regex - since it was working in IE and Chrome, I started from the assumption that it was syntactically correct. Google search and SO search didn't help. If I simplify this question it may make it useful for others, don't you think?

Comment: there's nothing wrong with self-answering. sadly i don't have time to cover all the quirks of char-range reserved char ordering as it relates to browser spec interpretation discrepancies, and i feel my overly-broad answer of "escaping everything" works but is less-than-ideal...

Comment: well, I appreciate your very quick help all the same :)

Comment: Parentheses inside a character class shouldn't have to be escaped. As Oriol points out, it's really the dash that's causing the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @dandavis said in a comment, escaping the dash works (no need to escape parentheses, though).

If you try to run the code

```
/[()-\s]+/
```

you get

```
SyntaxError: invalid range in character class
```

That's because Firefox is trying to use the dash as a range character, not dash.

To fix it, you can:

- Escape the dash: `/[()\-\s]+/`
- Place the dash at the beginning or end: `/[-()\s]+/`, `/[()\s-]+/`

Comment: thanks, these worked as well; you have explained *why* it wasn't working; and you have given me a tip for diagnosing similar problems in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, changing the regex as follows fixed the problem:

```
replace(/[\(\)\-\s]+/g, '')
```

Comment: ..sure, as a "better safe than sorry" measure, but it's unnecessary if you understand regex char classes!

Comment: Before this Q I didn't really get that *sometimes* you have to escape these characters, and *sometimes* you don't have to. I'm used to languages that are more consistent in that regard.

Comment: well regex syntax is one of the few things in the coding world that's almost universal. Sure, each language may have its quirks and limitations but the core syntax is pretty much the same.  It's not an inconsistency.. it's just that char classes allow for you to specify a range of characters by using a hyphen, e.g. `A-Z`.  So in order to differentiate that from a literal hyphen, you have to do what the accepted answer said.  The only other chars you have to escape in a char class is the `[]` if you want to use them, since they are the char class delimiter. Which again, escaping the delimiter..

Comment: ..is a pretty universal thing. Those are the only things that *have* to be escaped, and again, that's pretty universal in the regex world. Then there is that `\s` in there but that's for signifying a space char, not for making a literal s. And again, escape chars such as `\s`, `\n`, `\t` are pretty universal.  I wasn't tryin' to bitch at you, so my apologies if you took it that way!

Comment: I'm not using the word "inconsistent" in a pejorative sense, just in a literal sense. Literally, in regex (as I learned today, yay!), an unescaped `-` *can* mean a literal `-` character, or it may signify a range of characters, depending on its context. In this sense it is inconsistent - but of course it has well-defined rules which any regex writer should become familiar with.